# Mouse doesn't update outside the game window

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-2

I'm just getting back into GameMaker, since it's been a while. Upgraded to Studio 2 since it's all shiny and new and stuff.

My test code is quite simple:

```
/// @description Update position each step
x = clamp(mouse_x, sprite_width/2, room_width-sprite_width/2);
```

And it works just fine... provided the mouse is within the game window. As soon as the mouse strays outside, it stops updating. This is kind of a problem if I want to make a basic Breakout-type game, since it's very easy for the mouse to stray up or down during gameplay, and losing just because your mouse clipped the title bar of the window is a bit gutting.

Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere? I'm sure older versions of GameMaker updated `mouse_x` no matter where the mouse was...

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Studio 2, but you could try keeping the mouse inside the game window like so:

```
/// @description Update position each step
mouse_x = clamp(mouse_x, sprite_width/2, room_width-sprite_width/2);
x = mouse_x;
```